# sql select on multiple db's

Tags: sql

I got around 18 db's. All these db's have the same structure. I want to query all these db's once to get my results.

Example:

ShopA
ShopB
ShopC

These db's got all the table article (and also the same rows).
How do I get all articles in one result with a WHERE?

I thought:

```
select *
from shopa.dbo.article
     shopb.dbo.article
     shopc.dbo.article
where color = 'red'
```

Did someone got an idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you considered doing a `UNION ALL`?

So something like:

```
SELECT      'a' AS Shop, *

FROM        shopa.dbo.article

WHERE       color = 'red'

UNION ALL

SELECT      'b' AS Shop, *

FROM        shopb.dbo.article

WHERE       color = 'red'

UNION ALL

SELECT      'c' AS Shop, *

FROM        shopc.dbo.article

WHERE       color = 'red'
```

Or, with a CTE (if you RDBMS supports it)

```
;WITH allstores AS (
    SELECT      'a' AS Shop, *

    FROM        shopa.dbo.article

    UNION ALL

    SELECT      'b' AS Shop, *

    FROM        shopb.dbo.article

    UNION ALL

    SELECT      'c' AS Shop, *

    FROM        shopc.dbo.article
)
SELECT      *

FROM        allstores

WHERE       color = 'red'
```

Answer (score 1):

you could use UNION
if you can simply select the db names you could also use a cursor select with OPENQUERY on a dynamically created string insert into a temp table and select from that

Answer (score 1):

You can create a View wich is populated from your select as this:

```
    CREATE VIEW view_name AS
       SELECT * FROM shopa.dbo.article
       UNION
       SELECT * FROM shopb.dbo.article
       UNION
       SELECT * FROM shopc.dbo.article
```

Then you can try to run a query by the View

```
Select * from view_name
where color = 'red'
```

Then if you want write another query with another condition, you don't write another big query with union or other code.
You can just write a query on a VIEW